# ffmpeg fails inside PHP exec();

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am trying to get info from a file with ffmpeg, if inside php I have this code:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_directory/4.flv");
```

Returns nothing, even tough same command inside SSH would print a large list of file info (fps, duration, etc).

But this command converts the file properly, so I am thinking it is no permission problem:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_directory/4.flv ffmpeg_directory/4.avi");
```

It is the same for **system()** function too.
Any idea why that `-i` command would not return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_directory/4.flv 2> /dev/null` from the command line and get output, I don't know the answer. If it becomes blank, then I would say that when you specify an input file, but no output file, it is printing the output to standard error.

Comment: Yes, I think it WAS related to the output being an ERROR, I was able to do it by: `system("ffmpeg -i ffmpeg_directory/4.flv 2>&1");`